# Fastest way to create about 65536 sockets?

Tags: java, sockets

I refuse to take this question down just because you down voters don't know the answer.

**Goal**: Have the program capture every UDP packet regardless of the destination port. (I have accomplished this but it takes 10-15 minutes to load)

Right now I am creating slightly less than 65536 sockets. It works fine the only problem is to initially create them it takes several minutes(a lot of minutes)

```
ArrayList<DatagramSocket> receiveSocket = new ArrayList<DatagramSocket>(65536);
int i = 65536;
while (i-- > 0) {
    //System.out.println(i);
    try {
        receiveSocket.add(new DatagramSocket(i, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this process faster? It is a shame I can't just make a single socket steal all the ports or create these sockets like seven hundred times faster...

Comment: For what on God's good earth would you need 65 thousand sockets for?

Comment: I suppose raising the question, "Why do you need nearly every socket on the system, some of which may already be taken?" is a bit...much?

Comment: @AndrewG The problem for me right now is that it takes about 10 minutes or so to load up all the sockets. I would like to reduce that time to about 5 minutes max if possible.

Comment: @Makoto I need it because I want to capture every UDP packet regardless of the port number. Do you have a faster way to accomplish this?

Comment: @BrianRoach Oh but it does work. Just the initial loading is the problem. And your statement is demonstrably false as I have already done it.

Comment: Sure ... for some definition of "work" where you completely ignore the exceptions being thrown ...

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the socket side of Java, but is there some sort of listener interface you can use instead? This seems like an awfully bad way to do this, I have a feeling there's a better way. @BrianRoach +1, `continue;` is definitely what you __don't__ want to have in a `catch` block.

Comment: @BrianRoach I didn't say I wanted to bind EVERY port. Only every port that I CAN bind. Hence `slightly less than`. Which I did accomplish in about 10 minutes. It would be nice if I could do this in maybe about 5 minutes.

Comment: @AndrewG Java is no different than any other C style lang. You listen on whatever ports you expect to receive data, and attempting to bind to a port some other process is using will result in an error.

Comment: @AndrewG If you can figure out a way for me to steal every UDP packet or every free port please post an answer here. I want continue in the try block because that method throws a checked exception so I need a try anyway and I am using the continue to immediately try the next port. Why how else would you do it?

Comment: @BrianRoach Ahh gotcha. I am by no means qualified to be answering this question, but I thought I'd try.

Comment: @CodeCamper *"I need it because I want to capture every UDP packet regardless of the port number. Do you have a faster way to accomplish this?"* Yes: [jpcap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @CodeCamper Well technically you'd want to actually make sure the exception you're `continuing` from is the checked exception you want, and not use the blanket `Exception` in the `catch` block. Also, I noticed you created a `while` loop, but added code to give it the same functionality as a `for`. Any reason why?

Comment: Maybe look into jpcap https://github.com/jpcap/jpcap

Comment: @CodeCamper And if you're just looking for a general traffic capture utility rather than writing your own, check out [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (which is based on libpcap, which jpcap is also an interface to).

Comment: @ns47731 I am getting server not found on github any idea why?

Comment: @CodeCamper Probably an issue on your end, the link works fine for me. Go through their SourceForge site anyways. You'll find documentation and builds there.

Comment: @JasonC I need to have the packets in my program regardless of port number. Hopefully jpcap will work as soon as github stops saying server not found for me.

Comment: @CodeCamper ... http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @JasonC Should jpcap also be compatible with android?

Comment: @CodeCamper I don't know, try ["jpcap android"](https://www.google.com/search?q=jpcap+android).

Comment: "I refuse to take down this question." Umm, you don't take it down. We do, if we come to the community decision that it's necessary. Also, why make an attempt to offend us? Because it took us forever to get to what you were trying to do (which you should have said in the original post), which is fix the problem of the server switching ports, we were left guessing at what exactly you were trying to do with this question. Also, you yourself said it's _"overkill"_. It is. And usually _"overkill"_ will slow stuff down.

Comment: @AndrewG You just don't know the answer to the question. Also my question has nothing to do with switching ports on the server. I actually still want to do this. This is my objective, NOT how to stop a server from switching ports.

Comment: @AndrewG Actually if you notice I haven't modified my question. I only went into detail of a SIDE PROJECT using this code because he inquired about it in the comments. My question still stands exactly the way it is written so I am not selecting it as the answer and I will put a 800 bounty on the question if I have to.

Comment: @AndrewG It obviously is not overkill if there is no other way to make a program capture every available UDP port. The example below will inadvertently allow me to capture UDP packets but it requires special software on the computer so it is not even really Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do this, for a bunch of reasons, with the two most significant being poor performance and interference with system resources and other applications.

Instead use something like [jpcap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/), which is specifically designed for capturing network traffic efficiently.

Also, if all you need is a network traffic capture utility, and you don't *need* to write your own, there is always [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), which is based on libpcap, which jpcap is a wrapper for. It may be worth checking out Wireshark anyways just to see the power [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) (and thus jpcap) have.

Comment: _"interference with system resource and other applications"_. Yes! Please don't do this. You'll lock up every port on the computer.

Comment: @AndrewG My biggest concern is just the performance. I don't care about other applications, in fact I don't want any network traffic but through my application when I am using it anyway.

Comment: @CodeCamper *"I don't want any network traffic but through my application when I am using it anyway"* You will not be able to achieve that.

Comment: @JasonC The method I am using above is pretty effective, I was able to bind about 40k ports. It just takes 15 minutes to load... any advice on making that load faster as I check out jpcap?

Comment: @CodeCamper Yes but the other 25k ports you were not able to bind to are still available for use (or are already in use), and this also does not relate to non-UDP traffic. Your goal of having "[no] network traffic but through [your] application" is simply not possible. And no there is no way to speed up what you are doing. Why do you want to do this, anyways?

Comment: @JasonC I see what you mean, my main priority is to have my application receive packets from any of those 40k ports with a less than 5 minute loading time...

Comment: @CodeCamper Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @CodeCamper What exactly is this "mobile network", why is it choosing random port numbers, and why do you need to receive its data?

Comment: @CodeCamper What is the server?

Comment: @CodeCamper Er; when you send a packet from your phone the *source* port is chosen initially at random, but the socket you sent from is bound to that port and will continue to receive data on that port. So just receive the response using the same socket you sent from (the response from the remote peer will automatically be sent to the source port on your phone). It sounds like you are creating a new `DatagramSocket` each time you send a packet and then you are discarding that socket immediately. Instead, create one, and reuse it, and read the responses from that socket.

Comment: @CodeCamper Then find out why the port number is changing and correct your network configuration / code / whatever. UDP works, and it works well, and it doesn't require binding a UDP socket to every port on a system to work. This seems like a classic XY problem. You will likely run into continued frustration (ultimately followed by disappointment) unless you try to identify and correct the root cause of the issue here.

Comment: @CodeCamper See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401481/android-phone-development-udp-services (the comments re: wireless carriers in the answer, in particular). You may wish to contact your wireless service provider to find out more about their UDP traffic policies.

Comment: @CodeCamper Good luck. I'm sure you'll find some other good alternative sooner or later. Please check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) out for future reference. It will help you get better (and quicker) answers.

Comment: @CodeCamper P.S. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html (Even handles delivery of data if the recipient's phone is off or connection is down.)